# TOGAF 9: Example Implementation of Deliverables, Artifacts, and Building Blocks

Tags: togaf

I am reading v9 of TOGAF and couldn't understand the illustration of Deliverables, Artifacts, and Building Blocks.

Could anyone give a real example to help me understand these?

Answer (score 3):

Artifacts: Any chart or diagram, that shows an aspect of an architecture. For example a use case diagram, ERD etc.

Deliverable: work product that is contractually specified and in turn formally reviewed, agreed, and signed off by the stakeholders. For example a "A statement of architecture work" is an output of Architecture Vision that needs to be reviewed and signed off by stake holders. So a "Statement of architecture work" is a deliverable.

Building Blocks: A reusable component of business, IT, or architectural capability that can be combined with other building blocks to deliver architectures and solutions. A building block has a **type** that corresponds to the TOGAF content metamodel (such as actor, business service, application, or data entity).  For example an "OpenId Authentication" will be used as a SBB to secure the system and is a solution for the ABB "Secure access to portal.".

Answer (score 2):

Artifacts can be charts, diagrams.
Deliverables may contain artifacts.
Deliverables are work products that typically require approval/signatures.
Building Blocks are components of an architecture.

Check http://wiki.glitchdata.com and search for TOGAF for more study notes.

Answer (score -1):

Artifacts can be charts, diagrams. Deliverables may contain artifacts. Deliverables are work products that typically require approval/signatures. Building Blocks are components of an architecture.
Try this:
http://www.togaf.info/togaf9/togafSlides9/TOGAF-V9-Sample-Catalogs-Matrics-Diagrams-v2.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Something that may help you understand a little better is a sample set of TOGAF 9 deliverables. The Open Group provides a set of templates, including examples of all catalogs, matrices, and diagrams, and template deliverables.

They can be downloaded [here](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/i093). If the link is ever broken, search their site for **I093**.

Answer (score -2):

[Relationship between Artifacts, Building Blocks and Deliverable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA1tP.png)

Artifacts are documents contains catalogs and diagrams of building blocks and artifacts support building 
blocks. Solutions are the deliverable's generated from artifacts.